# Internet Explorer 7,8 content type issues in meta tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm having very strange problem with Internet Explorer 7 and 8. For example if I have on my page:
 `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` 
after the head tag.  Consequently, writing to textboxes is very difficult(its cursor blinking very fast and its text appears in 1-2 seconds) and also checkboxes, radiobuttons are also very difficult to choose. I changed it to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

and issues were resolved. But another one was appeared: dropdowns are behaving very unpredictable, for example, if I choose an option from the options, and if I want to change it again, its menu popup getting closed so I'm able to choose that option after 3-4 attempts. 
All of them are working fine on IE9's IE7 and IE8 modes.
I've googled around, but I could not found anything. Maybe I couldn't explain to the google what I'm wanting.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the environment you're using for tests? Are you using IE7 and IE8 on isolated virtual machines? What software have you installed for tests?

Comment: I'm using windows7, no they are not isolated VMs, I have not installed anything. Actually, our clients are complaining about it, It worked fine on my machine(IE9) on both ie7 and ie8 modes. But when i check it another machine(just simple machine for home use only), it is working very slow strange... as I explained above

Comment: And that machine has which version of IE?

Comment: Hmm well based on the information you've provided I can't tell you much. There could be a million reasons why this is happening. The most common one though is when you have things like MultipleIE installed. Other than that it could be because of some of the scripts you use.

Comment: Answer to my own question is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326726/solved-issue-clarification-internet-explorer-7-8-content-type-issues-in-meta-ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my own question is explained here: [Internet Explorer 7,8 content type in meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326726/solved-issue-clarification-internet-explorer-7-8-content-type-issues-in-meta-ta) .
Here is the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKyK_MDRxZI (one minute length)

Answer (score 0):

In general, it makes sense to use `IE=edge` value to force most modern rendering/functioning mode of IE. Otherwise, more modern versions of IE are forced to emulate behavior of older version including its specific bugs.

Comment: I also tried this, but it just forces if user has modern version, but for ie8 that's problem... thanks  anyway