# Internet Explorer 7,8 content type in meta tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313014/internet-explorer-7-8-content-type-issues-in-meta-tag) regarding IE8 issue. After some time the problem was solved by removing one css class from style sheet file. But I could not understand why removing one css class is solving my problem? 
Here is the link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKyK_MDRxZI  (one minute length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** that IE7 and 8 have a problem with the shorthand `font` rule, where you specify all the variations in one go - there's something it can't handle, but I can't remember what off the top of my head. Try splitting out into `font-size`, `font-family` etc and see if it fixes it.